# why module.exports return code as a text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

The problem I'm having is that when using `module.exports` I'm getting the output as text.

profile.js

```js
const dbProfile = require("./dbProfile");

async function User(interaction) {
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099ff)
    .setTitle("user profile ")
    .setURL("https://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
    .setDescription(`ExarID: ${dbProfile.profileInfo}`);
  await interaction.reply({
    ephemeral: true,
    embeds: [embed],
    fetchReply: true,
  });
  return 0;
}
```

dbProfile.js

```js
const db = require("./dbStart");

module.exports = {
  profileInfo: function () {
    console.log(db.users);
    return db.users;
  },
};
```

dbStart.js

```js
exports.users = function () {
  conn.query("SELECT ExarID FROM users", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(JSON.parse(result));
    return result;
  });
};
```

What the bot replies:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `the output` ... what output? `dbProfile.profileInfo` is the function ... `dbProfile.profileInfo()` is how you execute the function - I believe you want to call that function, not pass that function as the value for `ExarID` ....

Comment: To call a function you use `()`. For example to print something you do `console.log('hello')`. Not `console.log + 'hello'`. I think you already know this because you are calling `console.log` correctly but just forgot to do it for `dbProfile.profileInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never running your functions, and the `.toString()` of uncalled functions returns the source code.

You need to change your code to call the functions

in `dbProfile.js`

```js
const users = db.users();
console.log(users)
return users;
```

in `profile.js`

```js
.setDescription(`ExarID: ${dbProfile.profileInfo()}`)
```

---

You also have a bug in `dbStart.js` since you're never actually returning anything (see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/12101554))

This involves changing all your code to work asynchronously

`profile.js`

```js
const dbProfile = require("./dbProfile");
async function User(interaction) {
  const profileInfo = await dbProfile.profileInfo();
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099ff)
    .setTitle("user profile ")
    .setURL("https://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
    .setDescription(`ExarID: ${profileInfo}`);
  await interaction.reply({
    ephemeral: true,
    embeds: [embed],
    fetchReply: true,
  });
  return 0;
}
```

`dbProfile.js`

```js
const db = require("./dbStart");
module.exports = {
  profileInfo: async function () {
    const users = await db.users();
    console.log(users);
    return users;
  },
};
```

`dbStart.js`

```js
exports.users = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    conn.query("SELECT ExarID FROM users", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(JSON.parse(result));
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
};
```